# problem to include fontawesome 6 on magento 2

Tags: frontend, magento2

I have a Magento 2 project and I want to insert only the brands and solid parts of FontAwesome 6. I downloaded the CSS and WOFF2 files and placed them in the appropriate structure.
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJrHb.png)

Additionally, I added these lines to the default_head_blocks.xml file.
[inside tag head on file default_head_blocks.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuOvc.png)
However, it's not working; I've run the setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, and setup:static-content:deploy commands, but the icons are still broken.

Can anyone help-me please.

I am expected some like this
[icons fontawesome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v53b.png)
For now, it's set up like this.
[not loaded icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H75cB.png)

Comment: browser inspector, is there a 404 error? for the css file

Comment: no, the file didn't even appear in f12 - network
I gave up on the idea and installed this module, unfortunately only fontawesome-5 is available: https://github.com/swissup/font-awesome-5

Comment: maybe put the fonts in the web/css/fonts folder, instead of web/fonts , if you want your correct version of fontawesome